# Oracle JDBC: Disable cpu-intensive security features

Tags: java, performance, security, testing, oracle19c

**Oracle's JDBC driver** does some quite **CPU-intensive calls** during connection creation/authentication, like usages of `SecureRandom` (even though `/dev/urandom` is used in our case) or AES ciphers.

Example stacktrace snippet of an expensive operation:

```
javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(byte[], int, int, byte[]) line: 2325    
oracle.net.aso.e.b(byte[], int, int, byte[]) line: not available    
oracle.net.aso.ac.f(byte[]) line: not available 
oracle.net.aso.c.f(byte[]) line: not available  
oracle.security.o5logon.O5Logon.a(byte[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String) line: not available   
oracle.security.o5logon.O5Logon.generateOAuthResponse(int, byte[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[], byte[], byte[], byte[], byte[], byte[], int[], int[], boolean, byte, byte[], int, int, byte[], int[]) line: not available  
oracle.security.o5logon.O5Logon.generateOAuthResponse(int, byte[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[], byte[], byte[], byte[], int[], boolean, byte, byte[], int, int, byte[], int[]) line: not available   
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, int, int, byte[][]) line: 1179   
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long) line: 1025   
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) line: 743   
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection(oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection).connect(org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) line: 793  
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) line: 57   
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver).connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) line: 747    
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver).connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties) line: 562     
[...]
```

While this is fine for production and regular test environments, it adds unnecessary CPU costs and latencies for connections to special environments, e.g. in **automated testing scenarios** for which we use local database instances with pure testing data.

**Question:**
Is there a way to disable some or all of those expensive security-related features, e.g. by lowering or disable authentication of the jdbc driver or any other measure to reduce cpu time?

**EDIT:**

I am using a local on-premise database with more or less default configuration and plain username/password authentication. JDBC driver version is 19.3.

In our scenario, we have many short-living applications which create one or two connections, do some work for a couple of seconds and terminate. So connection pooling will **not** solve this issue in our case.

I did some more profling and in a test method, containing a loop just creating and closing JDBC connections.
**23% of the walltime** is spent in `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret()`, called by the oracle jdbc driver:

[image]

Comment: Err, don't use SSL?

Comment: @user207421 I've not explicitly configured any SSL usage.

Comment: Are you pooling your connections ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes. But in our test-scenarios, we have many short-living applications - and therefore connections, so pooling helps but is not sufficient enough as some applications startup, create one connection and terminate after a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Are  you using any new Oracle features?
Like OAUTH authentication, Oracle Cloud database?

From the stack trace it seems to be hard to avoid, this is part of negotiation where client needs to  encrypt password before sending it to server. I never saw this as a problem - CPU intensive password encryption.
There were problems with Java8 where /dev/random was blocking and client was stalled due to lack of entropy.

For testing purposes you can use worse encryption algorithm. Oracle stores multiple password's hashes delimited by semicolon.

```
alter user xxx identified by values '.... password hash'.
```

As documented here: [SpiderLabs Blog](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/changes-in-oracle-database-12c-password-hashes/)

Comment: I'm not using any fancy oracle features. It's a local database and authentication is by username/password (so no oauth etc.). Thanks for the link, I'll check this out.
I will edit my question and provide more details, stay tuned.

Comment: The /dev/random and entropy issue long predated Java 8, I think. I remember switching the JRE to use /dev/urandom a *long* time ago!

Comment: Wow what is that profiling tool? PBKDF2 is newest password hashing algorithm. It is something like n-times applied SHA512. So password's hash can be hardened anytime by applying more hash iterations without knowing actual password's plaintext. Try to remove this hash by executing `ALTER USER identified by values 'md5hash;sha1hash';`. 
PS: I assume you run unit tests and you open dedicated connection for each test and PBKDF2 uses to much CPU time.

Comment: YourKit Profiler has been used. In my case, the database user is a login version 11g user, so only the S: hash value has been set (sha1), not the pbkdf2 / sha512 hash, so there is nothing to remove... If I could onl y force the jdbc driver into the old O3Logon mode... Yes, each 'test' uses an own connection, as it is not a unit test but a functional test using short living applications.

Comment: So you can still enable old 3DES hashes by setting `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON=FALSE` - 
https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/04/24/having-some-fun-with-sec_case_sensitive_logon-and-ora-1017/ ,but still creation on a new DB connection is quite exhaustive operation on DB server side. Much longer than this hashing. But it also can be some kind of new JDBC bug/feature.

Comment: @ibre5041 I played with this setting and I can confirm that this changed code paths in the client driver (now seeing DES and O5Logon which called O3Logon), however, it now takes 50ms longer in average than with the secure setting...